# How do I add a button and add event to it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, button

I use this code to make a button in c#

```
var Unqualify = new Button { Text = "Unqualify", CssClass = "ActionButton", ID = "4" + lead.ID, 

OnClientClick = "javascript:ShowActionCheckList('" + lead.ID + "');", UseSubmitBehavior = false };
```

The show action function:

```
function ShowActionCheckList(id) {
    $("#divActionList_" + id).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

I read and found that this `"UseSubmitBehavior = false"` should fix the problem but it's not helping

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add `return false` at the end of the `OnClientClick` function

```
OnClientClick = "ShowActionCheckList('" + lead.ID + "'); return false";
```

Comment: It solved the refresh problem , but now i can't get to my function .
Unqualify.Click += ActionButtonClicked;
ActionButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: You are adding a server side event?

Comment: In case the button has a client side event and a server side event, you should remove the return false from the OnClientClick.
In this case the button will execute the client event and then post back and executes the server side event.

Comment: but without the return false the page is refreshing , how to solve that

Comment: This is a normal behavior of the page. The page should refresh in order to enter the button event. If u want u can register a JavaScript function that runs after the server side event finishes